# MySQL insert if not exist then update if two conditions are true

Tags: mysql, sql, web-services

My Table fields are

```
SELECT `ogr_no`, `yurt_id`, `kat_no`, `kat_ismi`, `gorev_bol_ismi`, `baskan_mi`, `tarih` FROM `s_yem_tem` WHERE 1
```

here `ogr_no` and `yurt_id` are my conditions; if they exist and true at the same time then I need to update rest of it, if not I need to insert. With two query I am able to solve my need but how can handle it with one query. Did many search. `ON DUPLICATE KEY` solves the problem according to one value but I need to check two of them.
The closest logic what I need is

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM s_yem_tem WHERE s_yem_tem.ogr_no = 101 AND s_yem_tem.yurt_id = 1) 
    THEN
    UPDATE s_yem_tem SET   kat_no = 1, kat_ismi = 'Mescid Katı', gorev_bol_ismi = 'Etüt', baskan_mi = '1'
    ELSE 
    INSERT INTO s_yem_tem ( ogr_no, yurt_id, kat_no, kat_ismi, gorev_bol_ismi, baskan_mi) 
    VALUES (101,1,4,'Yemekhane Katı','Etüt',0)
```

But doesn't work for MySQL. any suggestions please

Comment: MySQL expects statements to be terminated by `;`'s

Comment: You are trying to execute SQL-server syntax into MySQL.. MySQL only supports `IF EXISTS(...) THEN  ... ELSE ...` within functions, stored procedures and triggers.

Comment: ; is not the solution, any code suggestions would be appriciated my friends

Comment: @RaymondNijland how should I try ?

Comment: While it might be possible to write a query to accomplish this, I believe the extra constraint will require far too much cleverness in the query, making it a maintenance problem. I think in the long run you'll be happier checking the two conditions BEFORE you do a query at all, and adding the 'on duplicate key' clause if the conditions are met.

Answer (score 2):

This operation is called an upsert and in MySQL is implemented with `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.

To start, you need a unique index/constraint to identify the duplicates:

```
create unique index unq_s_yem_tem_2 on s_yem_tem(ogr_no, yurt_id);
```

Then you would do:

```
INSERT INTO s_yem_tem ( ogr_no, yurt_id, kat_no, kat_ismi, gorev_bol_ismi, baskan_mi) 
    VALUES (101, 1, 4, 'Yemekhane Katı', 'Etüt', 0)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        kat_no = 1, kat_ismi = 'Mescid Katı', gorev_bol_ismi = 'Etüt', baskan_mi = 1;
```

Two things.  I find `yurt_id` very evocative.  I don't think I've ever worked with a database that has yurt ids.

Second, normally the columns with on `on duplicate key` get the values being assigned in the update.  I notice that yours are different for several columns.

Comment: Thanks for the attention but same result as we talked with @Dave. org_id is student_id, yurt_id is department_id, doesnt matter I just need to check two fields, department_id is unique but stu_id is not so I need to check both to detect right person. seems like I need an other aproach

Answer (score 1):

You can create a unique index that contains the two columns you're checking, and that way you can use ON DUPLICATE KEY.

Comment: I am able to make just one field Unique according to server phpMyAdmin

Comment: Here's how:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_col1_col2 ON mytable (col1, col2)

Comment: Dave I tried what you said what I mean is two conditions should be correct at same time, with AND, && logic here   ON DUPLICATE KEY support with OR operation.. I am changing just one value of my kesy then it updates but what I need is here new insert in this condition.

Comment: Unique constraint will be hit if both of your target values exist in the same row (AND).

Comment: ogr_no is primary and unique yurt_no is unique and I am trying butt not working. if both same update happens if one false update happens(that should not , here insert should happen) if both fieald are different then insert happens